# Can't bind a RatingBar on the RecyclerView using Android binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I am using kotlin to bind a RatingBar which is placed on a RecyclerView but am getting the following error :

> Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:ratingValue' with parameter type java.lang.Double on android.widget.RatingBar.

[image]

I tried to follow different blogs on setting the value to the **RatingBar** but I can't implement it in the Adapter.

Below is my model class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "Results")
class Result {

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("ratingValue")
        fun setRating(ratingBar: RatingBar, mVoteAverage: Float) {
            if (mVoteAverage != null) {
                ratingBar.rating = mVoteAverage
                val stars = ratingBar.progressDrawable as LayerDrawable
                stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(ratingBar.context, R.color.rating_bar), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
                val roundVal = Math.round(mVoteAverage!!)
                ratingBar.numStars = roundVal
            }

        }
    }

    constructor(mId: Long?, mOverview: String?, mPosterPath: String?, mTitle: String?, mVoteAverage: Double?) {
        this.mId = mId
        this.mOverview = mOverview
        this.mPosterPath = mPosterPath
        this.mTitle = mTitle
        this.mVoteAverage = mVoteAverage
    }

    constructor()

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    var mId: Long? = null
    @SerializedName("overview")
    var mOverview: String? = null
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    var mPosterPath: String? = null
    @SerializedName("title")
    var mTitle: String? = null
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    var mVoteAverage: Double? = null


}
```

Then, this is the bindable XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="movie"
            type="com.movieapp.huxymovies.model.Result" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                            app:ratingValue="@{movie.mVoteAverage}"/>


                    </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Then this is my adapter class :

```
class ResultAdapter(private val context: Context) : PagedListAdapter<Result, ResultAdapter.ResultViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {

    public lateinit var mBinding: ItemActivitymainBinding

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ResultViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val result = getItem(position)

        if (result != null) {

            holder.itemActivitymainBinding.movie = result
            holder.itemActivitymainBinding.ratingBar.rating = result.mVoteAverage as (Float)
            holder.itemActivitymainBinding.titleTxt.text = result.mTitle

        }
    }

    class ResultViewHolder(itemView: ItemActivitymainBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView.root) {


        var itemActivitymainBinding: ItemActivitymainBinding
        var root: View

        init {
            root = itemView.root

            itemActivitymainBinding = itemView
        }
    }

    }
}
```

I think am missing something in the `onBindViewHolder()`, but can't find it out, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mVoteAverage: Double?` property of your `Result` class is a `Double`.
You `@BindingAdapter` method has a `Float` parameter. That's why the binding doesn't work. Changing

```
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("ratingValue")
    fun setRating(ratingBar: RatingBar, mVoteAverage: Float)
```

to

```
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("ratingValue")
    fun setRating(ratingBar: RatingBar, mVoteAverage: Double)
```

should do the trick.